# How to setup turborepo with sveltekit and pnpm

Tags: svelte, monorepo, sveltekit, turborepo

I am trying to add Turborepo to my Svelte apps but looks like the `npx create-turbo@latest` command and also the examples currently only support NextJs. How can I configure it to work Svelte and Sveltekit apps?

Comment: Sounds like this could be of interest https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/sd9meg/turbosvelte_the_unofficial_sveltekit_monorepo/

Comment: There is an open issue here: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2973

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After creating the project with turborepo starter you have to follow this simple rule:

> Apps and sites go to apps folder and libraries and configs go to
> packages folder.

Now you can create a few sveltekit apps in apps folder using sveltekit starter and create a plain svelte library in packages folder. I wrote a small blog post about it with the code example [here](https://nenadkostic.com/blog/turborepo-sveltekit/.)

Few notes:
Make sure you have package.json for the lib project, example:

```
{
“name”: “uikit”,
“version”: “0.0.0",
“main”: “./index.svelte”,
“types”: “./index.svelte”,
“devDependencies”: {
    “svelte”: “^3.44.0”
}
```

}

Update turbo config in turbo.json file to contain the svelte-kit command:

```
{
  “pipeline”: {
    “build”: {
      “dependsOn”: [“^build”],
      “outputs”: [“dist/**“, “.svelte-kit/**“, “.svelte/**“]
    },
    “lint”: {
      “outputs”: []
    },
    “dev”: {
      “cache”: false
    }
  }
}
```

Update ports for each svelte kit app in the package.json script block.
Run your commands from the root of the monorepo.

```
npm run dev
```

and you shall have all the apps running simultaneously or if you wish to build all at once just do

```
npm run build
```